# Sidestep iOS13 Native PointerEvents

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps, pointer-events

iOS13 implements PointerEvents but has issues (https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer). The polyfil I've been using for Safari (PEP / Pointer Events Polyfil) is standing down because it appears there is native support, causing things to break.

I've attempted to check for iOS13/iPadOS and set `window.PointerEvent==undefined` before polyfil activation in a vain attempt to get it to kick in, but no luck--assume there's a range of things I don't know about that need addressed in order to fully sub out a custom system.

I've moved on to alerting users of the issue, and telling them how to to turn off pointer events in experimental features and then reload, which works -- unless the tool is being launched from the home screen as an installed PWA, in which case the setting has no effect (!).

Is there a way to sidestep native input implementation with a polyfil via JS, or to force-turn-off an 'experimental feature' via JS, or to turn off an experimental feature for a PWA in any way?